# Load timeout for modules in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, module, cross-browser, requirejs

This problem is appearing only in Internet Explorer 9, works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

Here's my main file which loads all my dependencies :

```
// Filename: main.js

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
// There usage will become more apparent futher along in the tutorial.
require.config({
    paths: {
        jQuery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        Underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        Backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        JSON: 'libs/json2/json2',
        templates: '../templates'
    }

});

require([
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'order!app',

    // Some plugins have to be loaded in order due to there non AMD compliance
    // Because these scripts are not "modules" they do not pass any values to the definition function below
    'order!libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    'order!libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    'order!libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    'order!libs/json2/json2-src'
], function(App){
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore don't pass a parameter to this function
    App.initialize();
});
```

And here's where the browser crashes :

```
SomeRoute:function(){
    facade.console.log("SomeRoute");
    $("#toDelete").remove();
    this.user =  new User($.cookies.get('User'));
    var that = this;
    require(['views/SomeView'],function(SomeView){    // On this require
        if(that.user.get('usr_id') > 0){
            var view = new SomeView();
            $("#domelement").append(that.changeView(view));
        }
        else window.location = APP_URL + "/login#login";
    });
}
```

When I take this route, I get this error :

```
SCRIPT5022: Load timeout for modules: views/SomeView 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout 
require.js, Line 27 Char 311
```

But nothing appears in Chrome or Firefox and everything works.

**EDIT** : Besides, refreshing the page I asked for loads it perfectly fine. It's only when I'm taking a route. I have to refresh to access my other module content.

**EDIT 2** : After some additionnal testing, I tryed to add "enforceDefine: true" to my main.js and changed my require calls. Nothing changed.
Besides, any view called with this function...

```
        confirmView: function(idDialog, view, opts1){
            facade.loader("body");
            require(["text!templates/common/dialog/confirm.phtml"], function(dialogTp){
                var opts = $.extend({}, facade.dialog.defaultOpts, opts1);
                // Delete previous dialog with same ID
                $("#"+idDialog).remove();

                // select the view we'll set
                var el = "#"+idDialog+" .modal-body";

                // Create our template with our options
                var contentDialog = _.template(dialogTp, { "option": opts, "text": "", "id": idDialog});
                $("body").append(contentDialog);

                require([view], function(viewClasse){
                    viewClasse.setElement("#"+idDialog+" .modal-body");
                    opts.preLoad(viewClasse);
                    viewClasse.render();

                    facade.unloader("body");

                    // twitter modal instance
                    facade.dialog.events(idDialog, opts, viewClasse);
                    $("#"+idDialog).modal(opts.modal);
                });
            });
        }
```

... will crash aswell (timeout).

I seriously don't know what's going on...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem before, and it stemmed from trying to use `order` with normal modules, not scripts. From the old 1.0.x docs:

> The order plugin is best used with traditional scripts. It is not
>   needed for scripts that use define() to define modules. It is possible
>   to mix and match "order!" dependencies with regular dependencies, but
>   only the "order!" ones will be evaluated in relative order to each
>   other.

http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#order

In any case, you should be using RequireJS 2.0 which does away with the order plugin [in favour of the `shim` configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and keep you informed.

Comment: Can't tell you how it is going, I have multiples errors with RequireJS 2.0 and it's kinda hard for a begginer. I keep trying.

Comment: Thanks, I finally made it (helped with another post) and it fixed the problem on Internet Explorer using RequireJS 2.0 and shim config.

Comment: hi @Brut4lity do you have a link to the post ? What was it about the shim config that made it work ? Thanks